# Bio dishwashing liquid affecting kitchen pipes?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have a query regarding bio washing-up liquid.

We've recently experienced slow flow in our kitchen drain pipes, and the plumber whom we asked to have a look at them showed us there was some non-descriptive gunk build-up in the pipes.

We rarely cook with fat (we're vegetarians, and maybe fry a dozen times a year). Plus, we always wipe our pans, pots, and dishes with kitchen paper before doing the dishes in the sink.

We've used bio washing-up liquid for a long time now. The plumber told us that bio washing-up liquids can cause build-up problems in the pipes.

That sounded weird, so we had a quick search on Google, which revealed no information on such issues with bio washing-up liquids.

Would someone be so kind as to let us know whether this is a known issue with bio washing-up liquids?

Comment: It might help to add a content list of the washing-up liquid(s)

Comment: "Bio" washing-up liquid is a vague marketing term with no specific meaning. Washing-up liquids with such a description in their names could have any of a wide variety of compositions. Without providing more information about the product you are using, it would be impossible to answer. However, it certainly is possible for a cleaning agent to encourage bacterial growth (and potentially formation of a bio-film) if it is /too/ readily biodegradable, acting as a nutrient. This could be made worse by low water temperature, and leaving grey water to stand in the pipes a long time.